# Disturbing the foundations of mathematics

Tags: philosophy, foundations

I was curious of knowing if it is possible that an event "x" could disturb so greatly mathematics that we could be casting doubts on all the achieved results from the very beginning. I'm not sure if my question is clear enought, if not, I'll reformulate.

Comment: Certainly, if the axioms of mathematics proved inconsistent, we'd have a problem - that is, if we could prove a statement and its opposite from our axioms.  It seem unlikely, but who knows?

Comment: If by "beginning" you mean introduction of ZFC axioms then sure, somebody proving that ZFC implies A and not A.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't assuming anything at all.

Comment: @studiosus: Actually that might not be that bad for a lot of results, especially if the contradiction is due to Replacement, or the fact we can iterate the power set operation so much. A lot of the math we do can be reduced to Zermelo's set theory, which is notably weaker than ZFC.

Comment: One might have thought the inconsistency of naive set theory (early $20$-th century) could be a little bothersome. Most mathematicians did not notice, nor should they have.

Comment: Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory is only 90 years old. People did math for thousands of years before that. And set theory's already on the way out, giving way to Category theory and Homotopy Type Theory. So the answer to your question is that if set theory turned out to be inconsistent tomorrow morning, not a thing would change in the rest of mathematics. For example we'd still do real analysis using the real number axioms. We just wouldn't have the Dedekind cut construction carried out in ZF.

Answer (score 3):

Why not?  It may have happened before.

I'm not enough of a historian to be able to say how well attested this is, but the "folklore" asserts that the discovery of the irrationality of $\sqrt2$ caused an immense upheaval in Ancient Greek mathematics.  It appears that large parts of their geometry were founded upon the assumption that one can always find a "common measure" for any two line segments: that is, a line segment sufficiently small that each of the given segments is an integer multiple of it.  When it was found that this is not always true - and, moreover, that it is not true in such an elementary geometric case as the side and diagonal of a square - Greek geometry had to be completely recast, leading eventually to Eudoxus' theory of proportion.

Comment: So you're saying that if tomorrow the foundations of mathematics are proved false, someone is gonna be executed by a cult? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila sadly, nowadays people are executed (more precisely: murdered) by cults for things which are **much** less serious than the downfall of mathematics would be :(

Comment: Okay, allow me to rephrase, executed by a cult of mathematicians. :-P

Answer (score 3):

There are all sorts of "doomsday" scenarios that one can imagine.  For example, what if someone finds two 100-digit numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a \times b \ne b \times a$, as computed using the usual algorithm for multiplication?  I imagine that something like this would cast doubt on quite a large portion of mathematics.  I don't think it's very likely at all, but once we are willing to accept that weak systems like $\mathsf{PRA}$ might be inconsistent, then I don't see any systematic way to rule out such unlikely events.

So although the question is fun, I think it's a bit too broad.  It's just like asking whether it is possible that an event 'x' could disturb *science* so greatly that we could be casting doubts on all the achieved results from the very beginning.  Sure–what if things suddenly started falling upward instead of downward for no discernible reason, *etc.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if we can show that induction is inconsistent then pretty much everything we did will require a good thorough review.

On a slightly less catastrophic scale, if $\sf PA$ or $\sf PRA$ would be proved inconsistent, it might also require a thorough checking of a lot of mathematics done in the past few centuries.

It is unlikely, though, that any bridges would collapse, and computer software to contain new bugs, in case that it does happen.